# What are the algorithms that are used by default by Timefold Solver if you don't provide any configuration?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

From what I understood according to the documentation, Timefold Solver applies 2 phases to solve a problem, namely: Construction Heuristics and Local Search (that uses a Metaheuristic algorithm). What exactly are the algorithms that Timefold Solver applies when you don't have any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default with normal variables:

- Construction Heuristic

  - First Fit
- Local Search

  - Late Acceptance
  - Move selector: union of

    - Change moves
    - Swap moves

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I want to change Late Acceptance algorithm to Tabu Search for example, do I have to also adapt the Move Selector?

Comment: no, just `<constructionHeuristic/><localSearch><localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</></>` does the trick